# Как получить и вывести на страницу значения всех href c определенным классом?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как получить и вывести на страницу значения всех href c определенным классом?
Пробовал подобным образом, выводит только первый:

```
var getvalue = $('.header').attr('href');
console.log(getvalue);
```

Comment: @PavelGrishaev что мешает дать такой класс заголовку каждого блока?..

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, по которому и так всё понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте с [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) :

```js
$('.btn').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<a href="#button-1" class="btn">
  button
</a>
<a href="#button-2" class="btn">
  button
</a>
<a href="#button-3" class="btn">
  button
</a>
<a href="#button-4" class="btn">
  button
</a>
<a href="#">
  empty
</a>
<a href="#link" class="link">
  link
</a>
<a href="#link-2" class="link">
  link
</a>
```